# Go pprof not working properly

Tags: go

I'm trying to get pprof working with Golang.

--text seems to work fine but most of other options does not work.

For instance with pdf:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user/IdeaProjects/go_projects/src# go tool pprof --pdf ./src /tmp/profile578584736/cpu.pprof > out.pdf
sh: 1: dot: not found
root@ubuntu:/home/user/IdeaProjects/go_projects/src#
```

With gv:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user/IdeaProjects/go_projects/src# go tool pprof --gv ./src /tmp/profile578584736/cpu.pprof 
sh: 1: dot: not found
gv -scale 0
Can't exec "gv": No such file or directory at /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_386/pprof line 719.
root@ubuntu:/home/user/IdeaProjects/go_projects/src#
```

Is there something that I need to change in Go to get it working?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need `dot` and `gv` installed. I see you're using Ubuntu, just try `apt-get install graphviz gv`

Comment: Great! Thanks. But also when I go to interactive mode my gv doesn't work `(pprof) gv
Total: 189 samples
gv -scale 0
(pprof) sh: 1: gv: not found` Do I need to install gv aswell?

Answer (score 101):

For anyone on a Mac using homebrew that comes across this question:

```
brew install graphviz
```

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar error on Windows 10. I fixed it by installing graphviz from here https://graphviz.org/download/. After that I restarted my IDE, issued the pdf and png commands and everything worked

Comment: Just make sure to "check" the box containing "add path to your system for all user" while installing

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option for Ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt install graphviz
```